# Simplifying algebra indices (division)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify the following: $$\frac{(n+1)^n} {n^{n-1}}$$

The answer given is $2n$
 thanks in advance

Comment: No doubt $\;2n\neq\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}\;$ ... Either you miscopied, or misunderstood, something...or "the answer" is simply wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}=n\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

we have $$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}\cdot n=n\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$